# A bounded interval covered by finite open intervals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, real-numbers

If a bounded closed interval $[a,b]$ is covered by finite open intervals 
$\bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^n {({c_j},{d_j})} $, I want to prove
$b - a < \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {({d_j} - {c_j})} $.

It seems obvious by intuition drawing on the real line. But when I tried to write it out in detail, I found it kind of tedious...

My approach is to eliminate those redundancy parts of intersections in the given open intervals and sum up their lengths. But it feels that I didn't make it very clear.

Can we prove it in ease e.g. by induction or something else? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use induction to prove this result. You induct on the number on interval that cover $[x,y]$ $\forall x,y $ such that $x<y$.

For $n=1$ it is trivially true.

For $n+1$. Since $[x,y]= \bigcup _{i=1}^{n+1} (c_i,d_i)$ there must be an interval containing $y$ assume without loss of generality that $y\in (c_{n+1},d_{n+1})$. And assume that $x<c_{n+1}$, otherwise we have nothing to prove.

Then we can see that $ [x,c_{n+1}]=\bigcup _{i=1}^{n} (c_i,d_i)     $, by the inductive hypothesis,

We get $$c_{n+1}-x<\sum_{i}^{n}d_i-c_i.$$

However we have that $y- c_{n+1} < d_{n+1} - c_{n+1}$ adding the last two inequalities we get the result.

$$y-x<\sum_{i}^{n+1}d_i-c_i.$$

Comment: Your proof is so elegant, Then I'm clear about this. Thanks much!